# Trying to pass an advanced function as a function argument in Powershell

Tags: function, powershell

I have a CSV file with computer names. I import them and want to use each value to do something with.

```
$computerNames = import-csv -Path "C:\Users\fakePath\Desktop\Programming\Powershell\remoteAddPrinters\computers.csv" -header "Computers"

function Iterate-CSV {
    param (
        # Parameter help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [array]
        $csvFilePath,

        [scriptblock]$functionCall #?
    )
    foreach ($computer in ($csvFilePath).Computers) { # Computer is the argument used in other functions.

        Write-Host $functionCall.Invoke($computer)
    }
}
```

This takes a csv file as a param then loops over it. trying to get this function passed as a parameter

```
function Add-NetworkPrinter {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        # Parameter help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [String]
        $computerName
    )
    
    begin {
        $addPrinterCue = "\\printServer\printCue"
    }
    
    process { # This is a non-terminating error and cannot be handled by try/catch
        Write-Output "$addPrinterCue && $computerName"
        # invoke-command -ComputerName $computerName -scriptBlock {
        #     # cmd.exe /c rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /gd /n$addPrinterCue
        #     cmd.exe /c rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ga /n$addPrinterCue /q
        #     Restart-Service -Name Spooler -Force
        #                                     #Creates error to handle
        # } -Credential $domainCredentials  #-ErrorVariable errmsg 2>$null
    }
    
    end {
        Write-Output "Successfully added printer to $computerName"
    }
}
```

That way i dont have to write another foreach loop to do other tasks syncronously using values within the CSV, i can just make functions taking one argument, the iteration variable

Comment: Don't understand the whole point of what you're trying to accomplish, if both functions are on the same scope you can call them from the other function's scope. There is no need to pass it as paramater.

Comment: What actually works about your setup and what doesn't? As it is I don't really see any reason to not just use `Import-CSV | %{Add-Networkprinter $_.Computer}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to pass a `scriptblock` that calls your function.

```
$func = [scriptblock]{ 
    param ($arg)
    Add-NetworkPrinter $arg 
}

Iterate-CSV -csvFilePath ... -functionCall $func
```

Comment: This is great. I don't need advanced functions for what I need, just scriptblocks  with param() block passed in. Really great exposure to this thank you much!

Answer (score 1):

To reference the underlying scriptblock definition of a registered function, use the `function:` drive prefix to pass it as a variable:

```
Iterate-Csv ... -scriptBlock ${function:Add-NetworkPrinter}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an Advanced Function named Add-NetworkPrinter, I just created a scriptblock, as @Andrey pointed out while keeping my advanced function that iterates through values of the CSV file.

```
$computerNames = import-csv -Path "C:\fakePath\computers.csv" -header "Computers"

function Iterate-CSV {
    param (
        # Parameter help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [array]
        $csvFilePath,
        [scriptblock]$functionCall
    )
    foreach ($computer in ($csvFilePath).Computers) { 
        Write-Host $functionCall.Invoke($computer)
    }
}

$addNetworkPrinter = [scriptblock]{ 
    param ($computer)
    $addPrinterCue = "\\printServer\printCue"
    Write-Output "$addPrinterCue && $computer"
    # invoke-command -ComputerName $computerName -scriptBlock {
    #     # cmd.exe /c rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /gd /n$addPrinterCue
    #     cmd.exe /c rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ga /n$addPrinterCue /q
    #     Restart-Service -Name Spooler -Force
    #                                     #Creates error to handle
    # } -Credential $domainCredentials  #-ErrorVariable errmsg 2>$null
}

$restarComputers = [scriptblock]{
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [string]
        $computer
    )
    Write-Output "Restarting computer $computer"
    # Restart-Computer -ComputerName $computer -Credential $domainCredentials -Force
}
```

Then I just call my Iterate-CSV function by providing the path to csv as param1 and scriptblocks that use the same values for param2. Thanks for the ScriptBlock Info!

```
Iterate-CSV -csvFilePath $computerNames -functionCall $addNetworkPrinter
Iterate-CSV -csvFilePath $computerNames -functionCall $restarComputers
```